# How can I solve this import error in react native code, in Expo Snack?

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native

I am getting an error in a app of react native, while building it in Expo Snack

This is the error I am getting:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qPDd9.png)

Here is my code in App.js

```
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs';

import { View, Text, StyleSheet, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';

import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-native-fontawesome';
import { faBars } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons/faBars';
import { faMagnifyingGlass } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons/faMagnifyingGlass';
import { faGear } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons/faGear';
```

Here is the package.json file:

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "react-native-svg": "12.3.0",
    "react-navigation": "^4.4.4",
    "@expo/vector-icons": "^13.0.0",
    "react-native-paper": "4.9.2",
    "react-native-tab-view": "^3.5.2",
    "react-native-pager-view": "5.4.24",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^3.8.4",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^6.4.2",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^6.4.2",
    "@react-navigation/material-top-tabs": "^6.6.3",
    "@fortawesome/react-native-fontawesome": "*",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons/faBars": "*",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons/faGear": "*",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons/faMugSaucer": "*",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons/faMagnifyingGlass": "*",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.5.8",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.3.1",
    "react-native-screens": "~3.15.0"
  }
}
```

How can I solve this error?